# Classification of all "Big O equivalence classes"

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Given functions $f$, $g$, $f = \Theta(g)$ defines an equivalence relation. The equivalence classes of this relation are intensively used in computer science. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities for a list of equivalence classes. Now my question is:

> Is there a complete classification of all equivalence classes?

As a bonus question: Is there a classification of all equivalence classes of the relation $f \sim g$ (as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)?

Comment: Bonus question: what did you try so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything, because this is not my area, so I probably don't have appropriate tools. I'm just curious. It's also not a homework assignment or something. :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "complete classification"? Some formal concept or something else?

Comment: Not sure it exactly answers your question, but this sounds related to **Hardy fields** and Hardy's book *Orders of Infinity*.

Comment: @Ingix: Not something that has a formal definition. By classification I just mean a result which describes or lists the equivalence classes.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I asked this question once long ago (in a different forum) and the best answer that I got was that there are far too many to classify.  It is interesting to first ask how many classes there are.  Assuming that you mean functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then an upper bound is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ and a lower bound is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @badjohn: Oh, that's really interesting! Thank you very much!

Comment: I was hoping that someone would answer this as I would like to know as well.